# UDP client-server with select

Tags: c, multithreading, select, udp, client-server

I'm trying to realize a UDP client-server application in C using select function. I use it in the client to monitor both stdin and socket streams, and it works. In the server, I've a socket to listen requests from clients, and every time the server knows a new client I save a struct with client port, IP address and also create a new UDP socket to manage this communication with a single client and I also save the descriptor of this new socket in the previous struct. In the server, the select function is used to monitor the different socket descriptors, so the answers from server to clients are sent on an "exclusive" socket for each client. So I want to know if the select in the server is enough to realize a concurrent server, able to manage concurrent requests from different clients, and to serve it simultaneously, or I need to use a thread for every client in the server? Can someone help me? thanks.

Comment: Did you try it? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: In this moment, in the server there is just the select managed by the main thread. I don't know if in this way i'm realizing a concurrent server, or i need to create threads for every client.

Comment: Did you encounter any problems?

Comment: For example, in the client i have a multiple choice menu with the commands of list (lists files in the server), download (download a file from the server) and upload command (upload some file in the server).

Comment: I have launched two clients (the first requests the download and the second requests the list). In this moment i don't have implemented the download option but I have tried to simulate a big download inserting a sleep(10) in the server when he receives the download command.

Comment: I saw that if i request first the download from one client and then i request the list from another client the list of files arrives in the client when the sleep is terminated, so I have thought that the server is not concurrent. Am i wrong?

Comment: If you write sleep(10) then the thread doesn't do anything for 10 seconds - you are right.

Comment: So it is not a good way to simulate a big download

Comment: How can i simulate a big download?

Comment: You can start by asking: what is a big download? You will have to know how big downloads happen, before you can simulate one, and the easiest way to do that, is to actually make them, instead of simulating them.